# Clear the back stack of jquerymobile app

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am currently writing a jQueryMobile/ Phonegap app and I am searching for a possibility to go back to the first page of my app and remove the whole back stack.
So pressing on the back button again would bring me to the android home screen.

I should look like this:

Page1 <-> Page2 <-> Page3 -> Page1

1. Page1 refers to Page2.
2. The back button on Page2 refers to Page1.
3. ...
4. Page3 refers to Page1.
5. The back button on Page1 refers to the android home screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I use.  Override the backbutton behavior.  As your app progresses, manually set where you are and where you want back to go.

```
var current = "page3";
var backLocation = 'page1';
document.addEventListener("deviceready", deviceReady, false);
deviceReady = function(){
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", backButton, true);
}

backButton = function(){
    if(current != backLocation){
        //your page load function       
        load($(backLocation),'left');
        current = backLocation;
    } else {
        navigator.app.exitApp();
    }
}
```