# Correct page navigation on Phonegap / jquery mobile app

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am working with phonegap and jquery mobile but am having problems with going back on pages.  There are four pages:

Splash

Login

Main

SubMain

So Lets say the flow goes like this always hit the splash screen first. If a user has never logged before, they are shown the login screen, if they have then they are shown the main page. Here's a scenario:

A new user will navigate like this:

Splash

Login

Main

SubMain

Now from Submain screen, if they want to exit they will hit the back button until the they exit.  However this route will take them through the Login page and the Splash screen again, when I want them to exit the app when they hit back on the main screen.

Is there anyway to make the user exit when pressing back on Main?

I realize I could avoid this by disabling the back button and adding an exit button.

I'm not sure if this matters or not, but all my pages are in one single html file separated by divs with the  `data-role="page"`  attribute

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clear the back stack of jquerymobile app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264500/clear-the-back-stack-of-jquerymobile-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `navigator.app.exitApp()` is what you're looking for. As we keep track of the history manually our helper function looks similar to this:

```
function backKeyDown(){
    if(historyContainsInfo(){
        popHistory();
    }else{
        navigator.app.exitApp();
    }
}
```

and is registered via `document.addEventListener("backbutton", backKeyDown, true);`